# PHP SIMPLE_HTML_DOM_PARSER not showing some links on particular website

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'am currently learning how to scrape websites with 'SIMPLE_HTML_DOM_PARSER' and I'am facing difficulty , 
the page [click here](http://www.sitttrkerala.ac.in/index.php?r=site%2Fdiploma-syllabus-courses&prog=CM) as we can see has 3 columns

'Si no','code','course name' and many links under it . So when i execute the below code

```
    <?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.sitttrkerala.ac.in/index.php?r=site%2Fdiploma-syllabus-courses&prog=CM');
    foreach($html->find('td') as $element){
    echo htmlspecialchars($element);
    echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

The above code is only returning-

```
<td style="text-align:center">Sl No.</td>
<td class="style1">Code</td>
<td class="style1">Course Name</td>
```

There are multiple links under those td's and not even one is bieng displayed.
I also tried

```
    echo htmlspecialchars($element->href);//nothing bieng displayed
```

I think the dom returned does not contain those links see this code

```
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.sitttrkerala.ac.in/index.php?r=site%2Fdiploma-syllabus-courses&prog=CM');
    echo ($html);
   ?>
```

And the output returned is

```
Government of Kerala
Department of Technical Education
Login

    SITTTR Login
    Member Login

Govt. Logo
State Institute of Technical Teachers' Training & Research, Kalamassery
HMT Junction, Kalamassery - 683 104, Phone: 0484-2542355,
Fax: 0484-2542355, E-mail: jd_cdc@yahoo.com, sitttr@gmail.com
Main Menu

    Home
    About Us
        Vision & Mission
        Joint Director's Desk
        Officer's & Staff
        RTI
    Contact
    Institutions
        Polytechnic Colleges
            Government
            Aided
            Self-Financing
            IHRD
        Government Commercial Institutes
        Government Institute of Fashion Designing
        Technical High Schools
    Academic
        Courses
            Diploma Programmes
            Diploma Programmes (Evening)
        Syllabus
            Diploma - Revision 2015
            Diploma - Revision 2010
            Diploma - Revision 2006
        Diploma - Model Question Papers
        Diploma - Lab Manual
        Academic Calendar
            Academic Calendar - Diploma
    Training
    More »
        Notifications
        Orders
        Downloads
        Photo Gallery
        Important Links
        News & Events
        Site Map
        Feedback
Disclaimer
DIPLOMA SYLLABUS
Sl No.  Code    Course Name        //empty there should be multiple links under it
Important Links
Home
Sitemap
Disclaimer
Contact Information
State Institute of Technical Teachers Training & Research
HMT Junction, Kalamassery - 683 104
Phone: 0484-2542355, Fax: 0484-2542355
E-mail: jd_cdc@yahoo.com, sitttr@gmail.com
Website: http://www.sitttrkerala.ac.in
Contact Us | Sitemap | Disclaimer | RTI
```

Why would the links be not returning i tried curl too but failed.Stuck for the past 2 weeks.

Comment: I do not see any links. You must be logged in. Log out of the site, then look at that link. That is what your PHP code sees - an empty table. It likely only populates when you are logged in - since the web server is not logged into the service, it can only pull the empty table.

Comment: http://www.sitttrkerala.ac.in/index.php?r=site%2Fdiploma-syllabus-courses&prog=CM please view it again you dont need to login.Can you see many options like "English for communication-1 "etc.?

Comment: I don't see it either.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me why it isnt showing inside the downloaded DOM?

Comment: Why is it only showing the data on desktop version? Im getting really frustrated

Comment: When i go to 'http://www.sitttrkerala.ac.in' and manually click the option 'syllabus' followed by 'computer hardware engineering' i can see the data there. But if i directly tried to access the data page like this' http://www.sitttrkerala.ac.in/index.php?r=site%2Fdiploma-syllabus-courses&prog=CM' then no data is appearimg empty table.

Comment: It seems to work if I go to the syllabus link first, then to the link. It may be using cookies and/or scripts to detect bot vs human.

Comment: @Jim how can i solve the problem.?